# rewriting this python .ljust statement into more current form

Tags: python, string.format

i couldn't figure out how to write this another way (or should i say a more current way, like with an f-string or str.format). the goal is to print "Current activity" followed by dashes to a width of 26 characters as defined by a variable.

```
activityCols = 26
print("Current activity".ljust(activityCols,"-"))
```

any thoughts on a more current way?

i tried

```
activityCols = 26
print('{:-<(activityCols)}'.format("Current activity"))
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: The question back to you is if you already have a way that works, why do you want to change it?  This is exactly the case that `ljust` was invented for.

Comment: i was under the impression that ljust was deprecated and so i thought i'd figure it out without using it.

Comment: The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) doesn't mention anything about being deprecated.

Comment: ok. agreed. i was mistaken about that. i do prefer ljust

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.ljust` method is good enough,

If you want to try something new

```
original_string = "Current activity"
length = 26
character_to_append = "-"
result_string = f"{original_string:{character_to_append}<{length}}"

print(result_string)
```

Comment: thank you. that clears things up for me. passing the variable in brace brackets rather than standard brackets was tripping me up.

Comment: Yes, it is confusing a little bit. I tried on my side before giving you a suggestion. Please let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
activityCols = 26
print(f'{"Current activity":-<{activityCols}}')
```

Output:
`Current activity----------`

Comment: yes. i believe that's what i'm looking for. i tried '{:-<{activityCols}}'.format("Current activity") but that didn't work either. thank you.